# PHP PDO Undefined method DatabaseHandler::prepare()

Tags: php, class, pdo, undefined

I am relative new to PHP PDO and stumbled across this error while i was creating a search function for all countries containing the string given and gets updated every key input with Ajax.

Now my error is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DatabaseHandler::prepare() in E:\Program files\wamp\www\Ajax\search.php on line 27

Search.PHP

```
<?php
class SearchEngine{

    private $html;

    public function __construct($conn){

        $this->html = '';
        $this->html .= '<li class="result">';
        $this->html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
        $this->html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
        $this->html .= '</a>';
        $this->html .= '</li>';

        if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
            $search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
        }

        else{
            $this->html .= 'Something went wrong';
            $search_string = 'a';
        }

        if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM country WHERE name LIKE "%' . $search_string . '%"';
            $result = $conn->prepare($query);
            $result->execute();
            $result_array = $result->fetchAll();

                foreach ($result_array as $result) {

                    $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['name']);
                    $display_url = ''.urlencode($result['name']).'&lang=en';
                    $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);
                    $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);
                    echo($output);
                }
        }
    }

} ?>
```

and my database handler

```
<?php
class DatabaseHandler
{   
    public $conn;

    public function openConnection($host, $user, $password, $database){
        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }

} ?>
```

This all gets called from the index.PHP

```
<?php
require_once("cgi_bin/connection.php");
require_once("Database_Handler.Class.php");
require_once("HTML_Page.Class.php");
require_once("search.php");

$hostname_conn = "localhost";
$database_conn = "ajax";
$username_conn = "root";
$password_conn = "";

$conn = new DatabaseHandler($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn, $database_conn);

$IndexPage = new page();
$SearchEngine = new SearchEngine($conn);

echo $IndexPage->render(); ?>
```

Now i found that you can not call the ::prepare function inside a class. But how to fix this?

A few notes: yes my code needs some refinement but i rather have it working first, any suggestions are very very welcome tough. and the $_POST['query']; is for some reason always not set so i set the query for now to 'a' but that is a error i can find/fix later myself.

Any help/comment etc. is very welcome. thank you

Comment: Consider builder a better script please. The way you are trying to do what you need to do is horrible.

Comment: You are asking me to build a better script while this is ofcourse the best i could make of it?

Comment: Nope. This is not, by any definition of the word 'best' a best of anything. Other than best blunder. I am not trying to insult you, just to motivate you so you can do more (Because you can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$conn` is not a PDO object, it is the `DatabaseHandler`, which does not have any method named `prepare`. Hence, you are calling prepare on the wrong class.

Just call the openConnection() method that returns the PDO instance and assign that.

```
// use it like this
$db = new DatabaseHandler();
$conn = $db->openConnection($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn, $database_conn);

<?php

class DatabaseHandler
{   
    public $conn;

    public function openConnection($host, $user, $password, $database){
        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        // return the PDO instance
        return $this->conn;
    }

} 

?>
```

In this case, a PDO instance is returned, which should have a method names `prepare` and thus will work.

Comment: That won't work, I don't think. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `__construct` *always* returns the new instance of the current class.

Comment: I looked it up, you are correct. So workaround would be to just use the openConnection method directly. Will edit post.

Comment: I think @NiettheDarkAbsol is right, and if not could i get some more instructions i dont fully understand how to fix it. But thank you for helping me!

Comment: When you instantiate a class (with new) you are calling the classes' constructor, which always returns the instance of the class you just instantiated. What you want is a instance of the PDO object.

Comment: No one still seems to suggest, that OP's original script violates just about every OOP conversion ever written.

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg True but Meda's answer is incomplete. It's only half of the problem explained.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
$conn = new DatabaseHandler($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn, $database_conn);
```

As if the constructor would return a connection

It should be

```
$db = new DatabaseHandler();
$conn = $db->openConnection($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn, $database_conn);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. And i understand why it didnt work and why it does now. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @krijin one more thing handle this params from the db class you dont want to pass these parameters from outside

Comment: This will NEVER work without my modification to return the $conn property. openConnection does not have a return value in the original script. This should not be the answer.

Comment: @edwardmp Yes. The constructor *needs* to return the PDO object.

Comment: @edwardmp This suggestion works for me, or is it a sloppy solution and not "code safe"?

Comment: Because in your original code the openConnection does not return anything. Hence only if you return the $conn like I modified in my code. Then this answer is rougly the same as mine. This answer is just not complete because the missing part is dat openConnection should return the instance. @bivoc as stated earlier constructors can't have an other return value..

Comment: @edwardmp of course openConnection() should return the connection. OP better know this.

Comment: @meda no he obviously didn't because it wasn't in his original code. Your answer is not a working answer. Period.